# Packaging Tools which support for Linux machine

Tags: linux, installation

I need List of packaging tools to create a Installer which support for linux machine. I need to package few softwares and install all of them step by step in linux machine. To do this i need some tool. please can any one suggest me with best tool which supports for linux machine.

For windows I know  Advanced Installer,Install Shield tools. But these tools support only for windows not for linux machines... Can any one suggest me with some installer tools which package my application for linux.

Comment: You are going to have to give more information. Can you just give out the source code and let them compile it themselves? This is the traditional way. If its closed source then you will need to make different packages for different distros.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a tar.gz or a self extracting tar but it depends on the type of software you are going to package. Most convinient would be to use online build services like https://build.opensuse.org/. This would give the users the ability to install via their distro tools.